# find list of one item not in second list

Tags: c#, linq

I have following two list

list 1

```
public List<string> _strImportFields = new List<string> {"1","2","5","6"}

public List<string> _strImportFields2 = new List<string> {"1","2","3","4"}
```

I want to find all the items of second list which does not exist in second list

There is alot of example in so, i have tried all that but not getting the desired result

please help

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean with `all the items of *second* list which does not exist in *second* list` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var items = _strImportFields.Except(_strImportFields2);
```

it will find all items of first list which are not in second list, look here at [Ideone](http://ideone.com/h7K2hb)

Comment: will this return output 5,6

Comment: Yes got thanks, dont know y it was not showing me earlier, :(